# Getting error using mysqli and OOP

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I am getting errors in the script I have pasted below. I am not sure why I am getting them and need assistance. Thank you.

[image: error displaying image]

**mysqli_fetch_assoc-index.php**

```
<?php
//mysqli connect here
include('mysqli_fetch_assoc.php');
$newbookings = new booking();
?>   
<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-hover text-center">
        <thead>
            <tr align="center">
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Contact</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
            $newbookings->showBooking();

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){//shows error here
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php $row['name'];?></td>
                <td><?php $row['contact'];?></td>
                <td><?php $row['email'];?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php   
            }
            ?>  
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**mysqli_fetch_assoc.php:**

```
<?php
class booking{
    function __construct(){
        $mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','admin','homestay');

        if(mysqli_connect_errno($mysqli)){
            echo "Connection failed".mysqli_connect_errno;
        }
    }

    function showBooking(){
        $res = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM bookmyroom");//shows error here
        return $res;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You probably need to do `$res = $newbookings->showBooking();` instead of just `$newbookings->showBooking();`

Comment: You also need to make `$mysqli` public and pass it within the class as `$this->mysqli` and outside as `$newbookings->$mysqli` or the like. Possibly a method like `getConnection()` that will return `$this->$mysqli` which may instead be private.

Answer (score -1):

As I commented, here are specifically where I am referring to with notations:

```
<?php
class booking
    {
        # Create variable to pass inside the class
        private $mysqli;
        # I would look into dependency injection of the database instead of
        # creating connection right inside this class
        public function __construct()
            {
                #Store the connection to share with the rest of the class
                $this->mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','admin','homestay');
                # I would also check this whole statement here,
                # I don't think this is right. Try this.
                # Here is the page for this usage: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php
                if(!$this->mysqli) {
                    # You have to add "()" here------------------vv
                    echo "Connection failed".mysqli_connect_errno();
                }
            }

        public function showBooking()
            {
                # You get an error here because $mysqli is out of scope, but
                # using $this->mysqli would be fine
                return mysqli_query($this->mysqli,"SELECT * FROM bookmyroom");
            }
        # create a return method for the connection, especially if you
        # plan to use the connection outside the class. Again, injection
        # of a database class is more suitable...
        public function getConnection()
            {
                return $this->mysqli;
            }
    }
```

In the other page you would do:

```
# Since "showBooking()" returns a query, so you need to assign to a variable
$res = $newbookings->showBooking();
```

I should also note, it would be better to pass/inject a database class into this class instead of creating the connection as part of the `__construct()`. Also, I will make one final comment regarding connection type, I personally think `PDO` is more robust and easier to use, so if you are starting out, I would rethink using `PDO` as a connection instead of `mysqli_*`

---

---

**EDIT**

Since I have a moment, here is what you may want to do alternately:

**/defines.php**

```
<?php
# If you create some defines, you will more easily be able to alter
# your site structure without major rewriting
define('DB_HOST','localhost');
define('DB_NAME','homestay');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASS','admin');
# These are directory helpers
define('DS',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('ROOT_DIR',__DIR__);
define('CLASSES', ROOT_DIR.DS.'classes');
```

**/config.php**

```
<?php
# If you create a config file that you include in every page at the top,
# you can keep your site more easily structured
#
# Include the defines to help keep the site consistent
require(__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'defines.php');
# Create session here if your site uses sessions
session_start();
# Create a class autoloader so you don't have to manually include class files.
# It does require that you place your classes in the same folder structure
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    # This converts your classes into directory paths to the class folder
    $path = str_replace(DS.DS,DS,CLASSES.DS.str_replace('\\',DS,$class));
    # If the file exists, include it
    if(is_file($path))
        include_once($path);
});
```

**/classes/Database.php**

```
<?php
/*
** @description    Class creates a commonly used database connection
*/
class Database
    {
        private static $con;

        public function connect()
            {
                # If there is a connection already made, send back
                if(!empty(self::$con))
                    return self::$con;
                #I would encourage PDO here...
                self::$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
                if(!self::$con) {
                    die("Connection failed".mysqli_connect_errno());
                }
                # Send back connection for use
                return self::$con;
            }
    }
```

**/classes/Booking**

```
<?php
/*
** @description    This class is your booking class that receives the database
**                 to use, so you don't create it here, only use it here.
*/
class Booking
    {
        private $con;
        /*
        ** @param $con [object] Insert your Database connection here
        */
        public function __construct($con)
            {
                $this->con = $con;
            }

        public function showBooking()
            {
                $row = array();
                $query = mysqli_query($this->con,"SELECT * FROM bookmyroom");
                if(empty($query))
                    return $row;

                while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                    $row[] = $result;
                }

                return $row;
            }
    }
```

**/index.php**

```
<?php
# Adding just the config will take care of including classes for you,
# provided you have set up the classes into a class folder and the autoloader
# has the correct path in place. This would be at the top of every page
require_once(__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'config.php');
# Create the bookings here, pass the database. It may be beneficial to make the
# connection in the config file for site use, but I don't know your site
# structure, so that is a guess...
$con = (new Database())->connect();
$newbookings = new Booking($con);
?>   
<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-hover text-center">
        <thead>
            <tr align="center">
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Contact</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
            # Since the class already returns an array, just use foreach()
            foreach($newbookings->showBooking() as $row){
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php $row['name'];?></td>
                <td><?php $row['contact'];?></td>
                <td><?php $row['email'];?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php   
            }
            ?>  
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate downvotes and all, but without comment or discourse, what is the point?